# How to design a CoreData to store app's cache data

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, core-data, architecture

Looking for the best practices and ideas.
The problem I am trying is the following:
I'll try to keep it simple. In the CoreData there are entities: `Book`, `Genre`, `User`.

Relationships: `User one-to-many Book`, `User one-to-many Genre`, `Book many-to-many Genre.`

The user in this case will be in only one (currently logged-in user).

The app besides the user books will have other books' lists, e.g. suggested, top, etc.

I am trying to design a system where those lists can be cached(they are fetching page by page from the backend) in the CoreData, and trying really to come up with a scalable solution that hopefully has a nice design:). If you have any thoughts or experience on the design for the CoreData and the system, I would appreciate any insights.

Have a great day everybody!

Comment: An CoreData already has properties for that, look up fetch batch size. I suggest you look at a CoreData basic tutorial and look at the WWDC videos related to core data. Also see fetch limit and fetch offset.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum, I have checked it out. Will definitely rewatch it, to refresh. 
I am more concerned about the architecture for core data and how the fetching mechanism(high level) should look like. e.g. when fetching first page for suggested Book list, where the data would go, how I can hold the references? Should core data entities be cleaned up before that, etc.

Comment: All of those questions are opinion based and out of scope for SO. There are plenty of tutorials. But as a very high level comment don’t limit yourself to SwiftUI, it is still in its infancy and is very limited, the built in core data wrappers are very basic. You will have to adapt “older” code to make this work.

Comment: [Donny Wals](donnywals.com) has a great book, [Practical Core Data](https://donnywals.gumroad.com/l/practical-core-data) that goes into all of this in depth. It well worth the money.